# Mouse freezes immediately after starting playing a video file or game

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, mouse, freeze

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 into my new Samsung SSD. Installed the graphics drivers (GTX 960) and Razer synapse drivers (I have a Razer Ouroboros and Razer kraken headset). Also installed Steam and moved all my games over to the new SSD.

Now when ever I play a video file, or attempt to play a game, as soon as the playback starts, my mouse cursor freezes. If I close the video player/youtube tab or whatever (alt-f4/ctrl-w) the mouse cursor works again.

What could be the problem?

I have attempted restarting the computer, reinstalling graphics drivers/older drivers, reinstalled Razer drivers, different USB port, nothing seems to work.

Comment: could be a permission issue.. use Procmon.exe to trace events.  Did you install apps > run as admin.. could be an SSD setup for swap file or legacy issue... Group Policy changed?

Comment: I copped out :( Just reinstalled the entire OS again and the issue didn't come up again. Should I delete the question?